# Searching for a "Dry Goods Starter Mix"

Tags: bread, flour

Friend of mine had a dry goods mix that included things like flour, salt, sugar... it kept indefinitely and could be used in proper portions for any number of bread type items - muffins, pancakes, and so on.

Can I make such a mix at home? Where can I find sources describing it? And how can I use it?

Comment: Hi David, and welcome to the site! If you want the correct composition of the mix, you will give us some more details (brand, name, ingredient list, etc.). As for your question for recipes with this mix, I'm afraid this is outside the scope of this site. We do not do recipe-requests because of their open-ended nature. You can always come to the chat though for such questions.

Comment: I don't know the composition, that's what I'm hoping for.... beyond what I said above. It was a sort of generic "Jiffy Mix" that one could keep more or less indefinitely.

Comment: Can you edit your question to fit in the site without losing its essense for what your looking for? Coz it could get lost...I experienced that :)

Comment: If it's Bisquick or similar, I don't know if they can keep indefinitely, as they have a bit of fat in them, so you can risk it going rancid.

Answer (score 1):

This site has a recipe for the mix and recipes for using it.
http://kitchensimplicity.com/homemade-bisquick-mix/
Or google homemade bisquick

Comment: In case of link rot, the proportions given are : 5c flour, 1/4c baking powder, 2TB sugar, 1tsp salt, 1c butter or margarine; mix first 4, then cut in the butter 'til crumbly.